# If I were willing to let people hear the music inside me

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, expressions

What does the meaning of this expression convey?

If I were willing to let people hear the music inside me...

It is among the sentence completion exercises from Nathaniel Branden's self-esteem book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branden supposes that everyone hears music within themselves. He does not necessarily mean actual music but is using the term figuratively to denote positive feelings that cannot easily be put into words, just as the positive feelings that may be conveyed by music cannot easily be put into words.

The idea of completing the sentence is presumably to make you think about the positive effect you could have on others if they were aware of those feelings that are within you.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! This was the only one that wasn't clear to me. Now I can start the exercises.

Comment: Good. If you like my answer please accept it. Thanks.